# Android marquee backwards

Tags: android, marquee

in my App I am using marquee for some TextViews. Usually the text only scrolls in one direction when it can't be displayed completely. 
What I want is that the view scrolls to the left until the end of the text is visible, then stops for a second and scrolls back to the right.
I'am pretty sure that this can't be achieved with the standard marquee stuff. What would be the right approach here? Can I implement my own marquee behavior? How is that done in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the relevant code in Android that handles the Marquee](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.Marquee). It's pretty tightly coupled to the TextView class, so if you wanted to implement a custom marquee I believe you would need to write your own TextView.

Comment: Ok not quite the answer I was hoping for, since this sounds like an enormous amount of work but thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @Mondgewitter Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006252/possible-to-detect-when-a-textviews-marquee-animation-has-completed  One of the answers talks about animating text like you describe.