# Possible to detect when a TextView's marquee animation has completed?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-view

If I set a TextView's `ellipsize` value to `"marquee"` and the `marqueeRepeatLimit` value to `"1"` for example (in order to roll a long text across a TextView once), is there any way to detect when the marquee animation has completed?

(Thing is, I have a queue of Strings which is being added to dynamically and I want to pull out and show one of these Strings at a time. A String can be longer than the width of the TextView so I want to roll it across before I show the next one.)

> **Edit:** If it's not possible to do this by using TextView's marquee properties, anyone know how can I add an Animation to a TextView which simulates a marquee animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's not possible to detect when a marquee animation completes and even if I replicated the marquee animation using a translate animation on the TextView, it wouldn't be straightforward to set the duration of the animation the right length of time according to the text in the TextView. So! What I'm doing now instead is using a TextSwitcher as follows...

```
<TextSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/myTextSwitcher"
    ...
    android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in_slow"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out_slow" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

... and calling the `myTextSwitcher.setText("text to show next")` method every so often using a Timer. Not ideal but the best I could come up with!

Answer (score 1):

instead of marquee just try the simple animation on the text, there you can define in which style text should move, with what speed and direction.
You can set the result to show after the animation is complete by using "setFillAfter()" method (showing the default text in your case).

Comment: Is it possible to add an animation to a TextView that rolls the text within the TextView (like a marquee animation) and which doesn't move the whole TextView itself? Any links or examples or further info on how this can be achieved?

Comment: sure, you can animate it as you want. Do you know about the API Demos in Android? There you can find the code to animate the text (infact anything) with different styles.

Comment: API Demos is a large resource. Had a look just now but could't find an example animating text in a TextView. Do you know where I can an example?

Comment: In Views -> Animation -> Interpolators / Push

Comment: ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Animation3.java and Animation2.java

Comment: Thanks akkilis. Will check these out and let you know how I get on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7070/discussion-between-adil-hussain-and-akkilis)